# Easing in the blur filter

Tags: actionscript-3

Just wondered if anyone could help showing me how to ease in a blur filter for a particular movie clip?

```
treetrigger.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, rollovert);
    function rollovert (event:MouseEvent):void {
        myBlur.blurX = 0;
        myBlur.blurY = 0;
        tree.filters = [myBlur];

        myBlur.blurX = 7;
        myBlur.blurY = 7;
        man.filters = [myBlur];

        myBlur.blurX = 20;
        myBlur.blurY = 20;
        crowd.filters = [myBlur];
    }
```

I wanted to ease in all 3 movie clips by 1 second when i click on 'treetrigger' but i don't know how & where to put in the actionscript. Thanks!

Comment: The trick with filters is that you have to reassign `filters` property if you update the filter set anyhow. Therefore you cannot tween a filter's `blurX` and `blurY` just with a tween. You need to manually alter the filter set for an object via enter frame event listener.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a tween library to do this easily. For instance, using [Actuate](http://code.google.com/p/actuate/) the code would be:

```
Actuate.effects (tree, 1).filter (BlurFilter, { blurX: 0, blurY: 0 } );
Actuate.effects (man, 1).filter (BlurFilter, { blurX: 7, blurY: 7 } );
Actuate.effects (crowd, 1).filter (BlurFilter, { blurX: 20, blurY: 20 } );
```

Another popular tween library is GreenSock's [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) but any decent tweening library should be able to do the same thing.

Comment: awesome. thanks, gonna try that :) is there any way to do it just using the stock filters in flash?

Comment: @User000000000 Sure, you can manually apply the filters using an ENTER_FRAME event or timers, but a tween library will save you a lot of time and has usually dealt with most issues you are likely to encounter when manually trying to create a tween.